# Search user by field value using Drupal Search Api

Tags: 8, search

I have a set of users with field_first_name and field_last_name, and i want to create a user search using the search api, to search for users using those fields, but it doesn't seems to be working.

Here is my code:

```
$query = Index::load('default_index')
      ->query(array(
          'offset' => 0,
          'limit'  => 12,
      ))
      ->keys($text)
      ->addCondition('search_api_datasource', 'entity:user')
      ->execute();
```

It's not fetching any of my users per name. I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

On the first hand, can you check if your content is being indexed properly ?
If yes, then I would recommend using the default search box provided by drupal, and see if you get results.

Assuming you are using search api solr module.

Comment: I eventually found out the issue: i had to add the fields to my index and associate a view mode to the rendered user in: admin > config > search > search-api > index > default_index > fields. It was just a settings issue, my code was ok.

I wasn't using Solr, but the Database Server.

Comment: Cool, good to hear that.